# Convert raw sound into binary header

Tags: c++, header-files, binaryfiles

I found out, that you can save header as binary file and there is no difference for compiler when someone include *h file with table represented as binary values inside.

I need to save raw sound data into table for further read on microcontroller. I know how to read it and then save as text, but it is to heavy for me, cause i'll hold this data in small flash.

So could anyone tell me how can I save it as "binary" header? I'm not sure how exactly should it look so any tip or explanation could be very helpful.

regards

Rafał Kopczyński

Comment: How and where did you "find out" this about saving headers as binary files? What do you mean by "binary" file in the context of header files?

Comment: binary data must be converted into a textual representation and stored in a header as a valid C code. You may take a look at [XPM format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap) to get an example of such a format (xpm is for pictures though)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you need to create compile-time generated array with your binary data.
I'd suggest writing a simple help program, which would read binary data and write every `int32_t` there is as text, comma separated. Then you can copy all the output into your original program using something like 
`int32_t data[] = { /*copy-paste here*/ }`. Probably there's better way of doing it, but this works just fine. After the copying you can `reinterpret_cast` this array into anything you like.

P.S. There are no such things as binary headers. If(and surprisingly!) some compiler allows it, this is against standard.

Comment: Sound very rarely is `int32_t`, the common bit depth is `int16_t`. E.g. CD quality is 16 bits, 44.1 kHz.  So you'd generate a `int16_t sound[ ] = { 0,3,6,9, ... }` declaration. No need for a `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: Int32 just to make sure there won't be any padding issues.